# How to ignore StackOverFlow error in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I know why it gives the error, I don't want to correct it I want the system to ignore it and keep running.
I know that the recursion is not infinite and I need to know when it will stop although I am sure it will be in a very large number and after a good while of execution.

Thankssss.

```
public static int fun1(int begin, int end, int cont) {
    if (begin >= end) {
        return 1;
    }
    cont += fun1(begin, (begin + end) / 2, cont);
    cont += fun1(begin + (end - begin) / 4, begin + 3 * (end - begin) / 4, cont);
    cont += fun1((begin + end) / 2, end, cont);
    return cont;
}
```

Comment: The recursion cannot be continued when the stack overflows...

Comment: there is no way? the recursion I know is not infinite

Comment: "I know that the recursion is not infinite" Prove it. How deep do you expect the recursion to be, in terms of the initial `begin` and `end` values? Now, how deep does the documentation say the recursion is allowed to be, by default? You intend to halve the interval size at each step of the recursion, correct? So you should expect that the recursive stack does not get very deep, correct? But clearly it does, so clearly you are not consistently halving the intervals as you expect. Try to consider some cases where `begin == end + 1` and see what values are used for the recursive calls.

Comment: Errors are errors, and errors are important. If you could ignore errors, then the rules of Java would fall apart very quickly.

Comment: No, there is no way. With each nested method call, some data must be stored and it is stored in the stack. If there is no more space on the stack, the call chain cannot continue.

Comment: @JanezKuhar That cannot possibly address the specific problem. OP intends for the "problem size" to decrease by a constant factor (2) at each level of recursion, i.e., exponentially. The call depth, thus, should be logarithmic in the initial values, i.e., quite limited since we are not using `BigInteger`s or anything like that. Because a problem is observed regardless, the conclusion is that there is a bug and the recursion is indeed infinite.

Comment: You could solve this in a non-recursive way, e.g. creating a queue of subtasks instead of recursing.  Then you'd be bounded by the heap space, not the stack space.

Comment: Ignore an error that stops your program from running, that’s only possible if you ignore the fact that the program was running at all in the first place. It’s like asking how to ignore the fact that we cannot divide by 0. Or more precisely, how to ignore the fact that our computer has limitations, just pretending that it’s unlimited.

Comment: This problem is common enough. If you are _sure_ that the recursion is bounded, and there isn't simply an error in your logic, just increase the per-thread stack size until it's large enough.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that the recursion is not infinite

You "know" a falsehood.

```
public static int fun1(int begin, int end, int cont) {
    if (begin >= end) {
        return 1;
    }
    cont += fun1(begin, (begin + end) / 2, cont);
    cont += fun1(begin + (end - begin) / 4, begin + 3 * (end - begin) / 4, cont);
    cont += fun1((begin + end) / 2, end, cont);
    return cont;
}
```

Consider what happens if we call `fun1(0, 1, 0)`.

Is `begin >= end`? No; `begin == 0` and `end == 1`. So we recurse.

What are the arguments for our recursive calls? `(begin + end) / 2` is equal to `(0 + 1) / 2` is equal to `1 / 2` is equal to 0, with integer division. So the first recursive call is `fun1(0, 0, 0)`.

But the last recursive call is `fun1(0, 1, 0)`. Wait. That looks familiar, yeah? (Never mind the middle one; we have already shown a fault.)

Answer (score 1):

[@Karl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963893/139985) explains why your function is actually infinitely recursive.

But you asked:

> How to ignore StackOverFlow error in Java?

You cannot simply ignore it.  If you do that, the program crashes (or a child thread dies, or something) and you don't get an answer.

You could do this:

```
Integer result = null;
try {
    result = fun1(x, y, z);
} catch (StackOverflowError e) {
    // We are ignoring this
}

if (result == null) {
    System.out.println("cannot compute fun1(x,y,z)");
} else {
    System.out.println("fun1(x,y,z) is " + result);
}
```

But when you look at this, we are not really ignoring the exception.  We are catching it and (ultimately) dealing with it as a special case.

---

Note that you can get a `StackOverflowError` even in cases where the recursion is not infinite.  For example, if I was to add two numbers using recursion:

```
public int add(int a, int b):
   if (a < 0 || b < 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative");
   else if (a == 0) {
       return b;
   } else
       return add(a - 1, b + 1);
   }
```

Since Java (typically) doesn't do tail-call optimization, large enough arguments will give a `StackOverflowError`.

---

So what it the solution to `StackOverflowError`s in cases where the function is not infinitely recursive?

- One approach would be to use a larger thread stack size.  This could be done by using the `-Xss<value>` option to set the default stacksize for the JVM.  Alternatively, you can supply a stack size via the `Thread` constructor when creating a new thread.  However, the maximum practical thread stack size is limited by the amount of available memory, and potentially by JVM, OS and hardware architectural limits.
- A second approach is to translate the recursive function into an iterative form.  But note that if you simply simulate the recursive calls using a stack implemented in software, you have to deal with the possibility that that data structure gets too big.
- A third approach is to try and find an algebraic solution; i.e. turn this into a mathematical problem.

But note that there are some cases where none of the above will work.  For example, consider the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).